# DBFirst - Using MySQL Connector and EF6, How to recognize timestamp columns as StoreGeneratedPattern = Computed?

Tags: mysql, .net, entity-framework, timestamp

I have a table like so:

```
CREATE TABLE `incidentdata` (
  `IncidentDataID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `GUID` binary(16) NOT NULL,
  `LastModified` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `Incident_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Parameter_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Value` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`IncidentDataID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `GUID_UNIQUE` (`GUID`),
  KEY `FK_INCDATA_INC` (`Incident_ID`),
  KEY `FK_INCDATA_PAR` (`Parameter_ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_INCDATA_INC` FOREIGN KEY (`Incident_ID`) REFERENCES `incidents` (`IncidentID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_INCDATA_PAR` FOREIGN KEY (`Parameter_ID`) REFERENCES `eventparameters` (`ParameterID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8$$
```

When using EF 6 and MySQL Connector 6.9.8 and MySQL 5.5.21, updating the model via DB first always sets the `LastModified` column to be `StoreGeneratedPattern = None`.

When I insert a record in this table, the `LastModified` column is always 0 - because the default value in .NET of `System.DateTime` = 0. When I update the record, its `LastModified` value is then updated to be `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` as desired.

I have found two options that I can use as a workaround:

1. Manually change the StoreGeneratedPattern = 'Computed'. This is always overwritten when we change the schema (which is every day at the moment!)
2. Set the column to allow `NULL`, and then explicitly set the value of `LastModified` to null when inserting in EF.

As you can see both methods require some thought to remember to do something - and alas it has already been forgotten.

I have also tried to use OnModelCreating() to force the `Computed` property of this column but it doesn't seem to work.

Is there any way EF/MySQL connector can correctly recognize the `LastModified` column to be `Computed` when updating the model from the DB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have since moved away from MySQL and EF - there are minor quirks in its implementation, especially when using asynchronous implementations like `ToListAsync()`, `FirstOrDefaultAsync()` etc.

If anyone goes down this path, just remember that while it 'appears' to be working, I don't think it is stable enough, and the odd exception like 'read-only table' for example start to show when using async methods in EF.

There isn't a way to achieve my question using EF alone (but neither in SQL Server too).